# Why is this event listener function working on one class but not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I have x tables created with php and Ajax. When I call this function the first event listener works, but the second one does not, the classes all exist on various  elements, any clue why?

I expect to add a class of selected_row to the row that has been clicked on, but this doesn't happen for the rows with clickable-student-row, it does for clickable_time_row.

```
function update_clickable_times() {
  // Select all elements with the "clickable-time-row" class
  const clickableTimeRows = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable-time-row');

  // Select all elements with the "clickable-student-row" class
  const clickableStudentRows = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable-student-row');

  // Attach a click event listener to each element
  clickableTimeRows.forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Perform desired actions when a row is clicked
      console.log('Row clicked!');
      // Additional code here...
      const id = row.id;

      // Remove the 'selected_row' class from all other rows
      clickableTimeRows.forEach(otherRow => {
        if (otherRow !== row) {
          otherRow.classList.remove('selected_row');
        }
      });

      // Assign the additional class 'selected_row' to the clicked row
      row.classList.add('selected_row');

      // Perform desired actions with the ID and the selected row
      console.log('Row clicked! ID:', id);
    });
  });

  // Remove the 'selected_row' class from all rows with the "clickable-student-row" class
  clickableStudentRows.forEach(row => {
    row.classList.remove('selected_row');
  });
  // Attach a click event listener to each element
  clickableStudentRows.forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Perform desired actions when a row is clicked
      console.log('Row clicked!');
      // Additional code here...
      const id = row.id;

      // Remove the 'selected_row' class from all other rows
      clickableStudentRows.forEach(otherRow => {
        if (otherRow !== row) {
          otherRow.classList.remove('selected_row');
        }
      });

      // Assign the additional class 'selected_row' to the clicked row
      row.classList.add('selected_row');

      // Perform desired actions with the ID and the selected row
      console.log('Row clicked! ID:', id);
    });
  });

  // Remove the 'selected_row' class from all rows with the "clickable-student-row" class
  clickableTimeRows.forEach(row => {
    row.classList.remove('selected_row');
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please add revelant HTML to your question? at least with a few mock data to reproduce the problem

Comment: well do you call this before the table is added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching click handlers like that, you can delegate them to the document body ONCE. This will help you as you no longer need to worry about WHEN to attach them etc.. Just run this on the load of page, and when you add any new data, the event handlers will automatically work.

In the event handler, I'm first getting the target of the click. Then looking for the closest tr.
If tr does exist, and that TR's classlist has the class I'm looking for then the next step is look for A matching selected row. If a selected row exists, remove the selected class.

Then reference the TR and add the selected class. Then simply consoling the tr's ID for you to use as you need.

Also I'm using ID as a data attribute as I don't know if your IDs follow the proper format for ids or not.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  const el = e.target;
  
  let tr = el.closest("tr");
  
  if(tr && tr.classList.contains("clickable-student-row")){
    let selected = document.querySelector(".clickable-student-row.selected_row");
    if(selected)selected.classList.remove("selected_row")
    tr.classList.add("selected_row");
    console.log(tr.id);
  }
  else if(tr && tr.classList.contains("clickable-time-row")){
    let selected = document.querySelector(".clickable-time-row.selected_row");
    if(selected)selected.classList.remove("selected_row");
    tr.classList.add("selected_row");
    console.log(tr.id);
  }
});
```

```css
.selected_row{background:red;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="row-9711" class="clickable-student-row"><td>STUDENT</td></tr>
  <tr id="row-9712" class="clickable-student-row"><td>STUDENT</td></tr>
  <tr id="row-9713" class="clickable-time-row"><td>TIME</td></tr>
  <tr id="row-9714" class="clickable-time-row"><td>time</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I know I can do this. The reason I wanted to be able to do it as a function is that I add rows dynamically via Ajax so need to be able to call this whenever something changes. I  appreciate the help!

Comment: Actually, just noticed. Here is a sample row: <tr id="row-97" class="clickable-time-row selected_row"><td colspan="2">11:15-11:45</td></tr>
<td colspan="2">11:15-11:45</td>
<tr id="row-97" class="clickable-time-row selected_row"><td colspan="2">11:15-11:45</td></tr> When I click on this or any other row, the ID is not show. The log shows "Undefined".

Comment: @ChrisMcCartney, that is the thing, with this you don't need to call it as a function when you add dynamic data. By delegating the click handler to the body ONCE on page load, the dynamic data will work with it too. I also updated my code to use ID instead of data-id.